# Overriding data in a block

Tags: 6, hooks, blocks

I have a block manually created through the drupal admin panel.

I would like to override it in order to implement in it an array of data with it's corresponding html.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I also could create the block programmatically with the hook_block instead of using the admin panel.

I don't mind doing it either way, which way do you recommend?

Comment: `hook_block` is a MUCH better option than running the PHP filter in a generated block.  I'm assuming you're running D6 as you refer to `hook_block` and not `hook_block_info` etc?

Comment: I forgot the tag but as you say I'm talking about drupal6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use array in static block(created through admin panel) also by choosing text format to "php Code". What exactly, you want to achieve ?

Comment: To form the array I have to use db_query, I don't know if I can use the "php Code" option in order to do that.